# Angular - Proper way of doing this

Tags: angular

In Angular I have dropdown that is populated with values from variable. I also have an array of statuses that should be disabled from the dropdown.

So when there is option that has one of the statuses, I want to disable it, add title property to it and add class text-warning to it.

Here is actual code

```
readonly disabledServiceOptions: string[] = ['PA', 'PD', 'PC'];
```

and html

```
<select class="form-control customDropdown" formControlName="option" (change)="onOptionChange(pointIndex)" [(ngModel)]="this.formData[pointIndex].option" required>
<option [ngValue]="this.formData[pointIndex].option" *ngIf="this.formData[pointIndex].disabled">{{ this.formData[pointIndex].optionName }}</option>
<option [ngValue]="null" disabled>Select option</option>
<option *ngFor="let option of filteredServicesList[pointIndex]; "
        [ngClass]="{'text-warning' : disabledServiceOptions.indexOf(option.Status) > -1}"
        [ngValue]="option.ServiceCode"
        [disabled]="disabledServiceOptions.indexOf(option.Status) > -1"
        [title]="disabledServiceOptions.indexOf(option.Status) > -1 ? 'Some description' : ''">
  {{ option.ServiceName }}
</option>
```

But in the end, I ended up with doing same thing 3 times in same block (searching for option status in disabledServiceOptions array). I mean, that array has only 3 elements so I guess it's not a big deal in this case, but I would like to know what is actually best way to acomplish this?

Data in filteredServicesList array is gathered from DB and there is no much I can do about that.
Only thing I came up with was to expand filteredServicesList type with additional field, loop through array once I populate it and add this info in it. But it seems even worse, adding additional loop through this array just for this.

So really need advice what is proper way of doing this

If you need any additional part of code, just ask, but I can't provide entire app code

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me your code looks good as it is. I don't know if you like this better but you could always map the data inside the `ngFor` loop. Something like this;

```
<option *ngFor="let option of filteredServicesList[pointIndex].map(x => ({ data: x, disable: disabledServiceOptions.indexOf(x.Status) > -1 })); "
        [ngClass]="{'text-warning' : option.disable}"
        [ngValue]="option.data.ServiceCode"
        [disabled]="option.disable"
        [title]="option.disable ? 'Some description' : ''">
  {{ option.data.ServiceName }}
</option>
```